# jasper: listing all key-values pairs of a collection

Tags: jasper-reports

In jasper I have to print a collection without knowing in advance the keys, because they are programmatic and can change over time. Let me do an example of this list:

1. formData[0]={addictions=1, workout=0, allergies=1, selfSufficiency=0}
2. formData[1]={gastricNose=1, weightChange=1, diet=XXXX}
3. [...]
4. formData[12]={dailyAmount=12, latestDate={type=date, value=1542582000000}, ostomy=1, ostomyType=AA, ostomyBag=BB}

How can I print a list of all these keys/values so that they get all listed properly like this? I can already print these objects raw in a list but they obviously look pretty much like the example I wrote above, while instead I need jasper to cycle through each of the elements by itself and retrieve the keys and the value for each element.

This is what I'm trying to print:

- addictions: 1
- workout: 0
- [...]
- gastricNose: 1
- weightChange: 1
- [...]
- dailyAmount: 12
- latestDate: 18/11/2018
- [...]

In all posts I've looked into I'm required to know at least the name of the keys, but in my case I can't. And I cannot modify the data source structure either (for instance formatting the collection to be {key:"addictions",value:"1"} can't do that).

Thanks for your hints

Comment: One way is to create a method in java that takes the json which return a JRDatasource, hence you call this from jasper.

Comment: Do you mean a java class embedded somehow in jaspersoft studio, then built all together?

Comment: Yes exactly a class that supply the datasource you need

Comment: The existing backend application is already feeding the report with this data and I cannot change it. I can only twiddle with jaspersoft studio. Unless there is a way to pack a java class into a jasper report to "modify" the incoming datasource that being almost a total jasper noob I'm not aware of.